# Beamer \pause with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, pause

Is there a way to introduce parts of a `tikzpicture` with `\pause` or similar in Beamer without resorting to incrementally redrawing the `tikzpicture` over multiple frames?

Intercalating TikZ draw commands with `\pause` commands creates new frames, but introduces (or in my case, using `\setbeamercovered{highly dynamic}`, fades in) the entire `tikzpicture`, which sort of makes sense, as the interior of a `tikzpicture` is not the normal environment for `\pause` commands.

Comment: Potentially relevant question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9094/beamer-vs-tikz-uncover-nodes-step-by-step

Comment: Thankyou, John Kitzmiller's example was rather enlightening.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The easiest way to do this that I have found is to provide overlay specifications to the elements of the picture.  The basic commands, `\path`, `\draw`, `\node` and so forth are all overlay-aware.  The one thing to be ware of is that the bounding box might jump around a bit as different parts of the drawing are put in or taken out.  However, once you're aware of that then it's easy to fix.  Either specify the bounding box at the start (using the `\useasboundingbox`) or litter your drawing with lots of `\coordinate`s which are there all the time but only use them on specific slides.

Here's a fairly detailed example with the `\useasboundingbox` technique.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\useasboundingbox (-5.2,-3.1) rectangle (5.2,3.1);
\fill[gray!25] (-5.2,-3.1) rectangle (-0.2,3.1);
\draw[ultra thick,red] (-5,0) -- (-0.4,0);
\draw[ultra thick] (-2.7,-3) -- (-2.7,3);
\foreach \t in {-1.5,-1.4,...,1.5} {
\pgfmathsetmacro{\l}{abs(\t/1.5)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\m}{1 - \l}
\definecolor{currentcolor}{rgb}{\l,0,\m}
\draw[color=currentcolor] (-5,\t) -- (-0.4,\t);
};
\foreach \t in {1.6,1.7,...,3} {
\pgfmathsetmacro{\l}{2-abs(\t/1.5)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\m}{1 - \l}
\definecolor{currentcolor}{rgb}{\l,0,\m}
\draw<.(4)->[color=currentcolor] (-5,\t) -- (-0.4,\t);
\draw<.(4)->[color=currentcolor] (-5,-\t) -- (-0.4,-\t);
};
\fill<.(2)->[gray!25] (5.2,-3.1) rectangle (0.2,3.1);
\draw<.(2)->[ultra thick,red] (5,0) -- (0.4,0);
\draw<.(2)->[ultra thick] (2.7,-3) -- (2.7,3);
\foreach \t in {-2,-1.9,...,2} {
\pgfmathsetmacro{\l}{abs(\t/2)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\m}{1 - \l}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{2.3*cos(90*\t)};
\pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{2.3*sin(90*\t)};
\definecolor{currentcolor}{rgb}{\l,0,\m}
\draw<.(3)->[color=currentcolor] (2.7,0) -- +(\x,\y);
};

\end{tikzpicture}

\visible<2->{\(z \mapsto e^{z}\)}
\end{center}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

First frame:

[image: first frame of exponential]

Last frame:

[image: last frame of exponential]

(If there's a specific situation that you need help figuring out, either edit the question to include the code or ask a new question about it.)

Comment: My current method is essentially analogous to yours, except that I'm redrawing the `tikzpicture` with added material on new `frame`s. I see that the reason why my `pause` was not working was because I was attempting to uncover an `addplot`, whereas it works perfectly well for my `\draw` elements as evinced by John Kitzmiller's example in the question Aaron linked. Anyhow, thanks for the example as `\useasboundingbox` is useful to me.