# How to overlap images in a beamer slide?

Tags: beamer, graphics

I'm creating a `beamer` presentation. I want to make one *frame* that has a couple of images overlapped, like a stack of photos. Actually, I want something like this:

```
.-----.
| AAA |
| AAA |
'-----'
```

Then, the next slide shows:

```
.-----.
| AAA |
| AA.-----.
'---| BBB |
    | BBB |
    '-----'
```

And then, the next one shows:

```
.-----.
| AAA |
| AA.-----.
'.-----.B |
 | CCC |B |
 | CCC |--'
 '-----'
```

The idea is to control the position of each image and allow them to overlap. I have no idea about how to do this in beamer.

I think the best solution is to have all images inside the same `frame`, but put a `\pause` command between them.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

A TikZ example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}   
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (img1) {\includegraphics[height=3cm]{img1}};
  \pause
  \node (img2) at (img1.south east) {\includegraphics[height=3cm]{img2}};
  \pause
  \node (img3) at (img2.south west) [yshift=1cm] {\includegraphics[height=3cm]{img3}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The second and third images are placed on a corner of the previous image, the third also shifted a little upward, the reason being that with the images I used there was some whitespace between them. You could of course place the images at specific coordinates, and not relative to each other like here.

Comment: I'm trying this, but adding `\pause` inside `tikzpicture` will prevent beamer from adding the slide footer. Any idea about how to fix it?

Comment: Two solutions: use `\uncover` or `\onslide` - http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9094/beamer-vs-tikz-uncover-nodes-step-by-step - http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21512/pause-in-tikzpicture-breaks-footline

Comment: All answers here are great, but I'm marking this one as accepted because that's the one I've actually used.

Answer (score 53):

Can be done with the simple LaTeX command `\put` without any additional package. The units are in pt, but if you prefer other units then you can set it by for example: `\unitlength=1cm`. The values are always measured from the current point. In my example from the beginning of the line

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx}%% Only for demo here
\documentclass{beamer}
\def\Put(#1,#2)#3{\leavevmode\makebox(0,0){\put(#1,#2){#3}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\includegraphics[height=3cm]{img1}\pause

\Put(10,50){\color{blue}\includegraphics[height=3cm]{img2}}\pause

\Put(100,30){\color{red}\includegraphics[height=3cm]{img3}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Those coordinates `(10,50)` and `(100,30)` are measured in what unit?

Comment: in pt, but if you prefer other units then you can set it by for example: `\unitlength=1cm`. The values are always measured from the current point. In my example from the beginning of the line

Comment: Herbert, thanks for providing a simple solution that avoids the mysterious complexity of tikz.

Comment: I tried to use this solution to put two images exactly one over the other. So I used two calls to "\Put(0,0)", but, the second image was pushed slightly to the right.  I had to change the second call to "\Put(-9,0)" to aligh them.

Comment: I suppose that you had a trailing space. At the end of the first `\put...` you need a `%`

Comment: Amazing solution. Thanks! It really spared me a huge headache to figure out Tikz positioning hassle

Comment: Could please suggest what if I want red one as tilted form (diagonal sort of) overlapping both images.

Answer (score 5):

You can place all three images at absolute positions using the `textpos` package (see also [Absolute positioning in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6185/absolute-positioning-in-beamer)). A further method would be to use TikZ to place the three images in own coordinate system inside a `tikzpicture`. Both pacakges should work very well with `beamer`. The animation can be added using `\pause` or another overlay macro of beamer.