# Latex syntax: parenthesis for \makebox(0,0)

Tags: tex-core

Just wondering where I can find documentation for the following syntax, which is shown at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34929/187592?

```
\makebox(0,0){}
```

I thought only `[]` or `{}` are the valid brackets for the macros? Is parenthesis tex or latex syntax? Could not find the answer on the web.

Comment: Round parentheses are the so-called picture mode arguments and widely used by graphical tools like picture mode, TikZ etc. to denote x and y coordinate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are quite a number of argument delimiters in use. Standard for an optional argument is `[]`. But `()` (picture mode, tikz) and `<>` (beamer) is used a lot too. For verbatim input you can use `\verb+some text+`. Quotes have also been used.

But the braces `{}` are the only "real" argument delimiters. They must be matched, that means for every opening brace they should be a closing brace and they can nested: an argument  `{abc {xyz} def}` will correctly find the closing brace and be read as `abc {xyz} def`.

All other argument delimiters work by looking for a char and then searching for a matching closing char. This means that one has to be a bit careful with the input. 
With standard LaTeX commands e.g. `[abc [xyz] def]` will be give you the argument `abc [xyz` unless you protect the inner bracket with braces: `[abc {[xyz]} def]`. With commands defined with xparse `[abc [xyz] def]` will work, but here one would have to protect an unmatched opening delimiter: `[abc {[}xyz def]`

Comment: Perhaps not `xparse` behaviour in the last paragraph?

Comment: @JosephWright I never realized that xparse is actually matching such delimiters too. That is not really obvious from the documentation imho. It only says for for e.g. `o` "A standard LATEX optional argument".