# Position figures by \put and add text below in beamer

Tags: beamer, floats, captions, positioning

I am attempting to work through nice (absolute) positioning in beamer for a presentation. I decided to avoid `tickz` because I am running short on time. So I found a [nice post here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34921/how-to-overlap-images-in-a-beamer-slide/34929#comment1383995_34929) that offers a simple solution using `\put`. I am however attempting to extend that solution to add some text below my figure. Say for example:

The original example is (copied from the post):

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx}%% Only for demo here
\documentclass{beamer}
\def\Put(#1,#2)#3{\leavevmode\makebox(0,0){\put(#1,#2){#3}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\includegraphics[height=3cm]{img1}\pause
\Put(10,50){\color{blue}\includegraphics[height=3cm]{img2}}\pause
\Put(100,30){\color{red}\includegraphics[height=3cm]{img3}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

And I want to have for example a text with 'black', 'blue' and 'red' positioned at the bottom of each rectangle.

I thought to simply define:

```
\def\Putt(#1,#2){\put(#1,#2)\minipage{#}}
```

but it does not work. It gives me some strange error:

```
! You can't use `\raise' in internal vertical mode.
```

I say strange, because in principle, I am leaving out [\leavevmode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22852/function-and-usage-of-leavevmode) in my new command. Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

`minipage` is an environment hence you cannot use `\minipage{...}` alone. Instead, you can wrap the `figure` environment in a `varwidth`, then use `varwidth` as the third argument of `\Put`.

An example:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx}%% Only for demo here
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\def\Put(#1,#2)#3{\leavevmode\makebox(0,0){\put(#1,#2){#3}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-a}\pause

  \Put(10,50){%
    \begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
      \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \color{blue}\includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-b}
        \caption{Title}
      \end{figure}
    \end{varwidth}%
  }\pause

  \Put(100,30){\color{red}\includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-c}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @muzimzhi Thank you! I thought it could be easier. But this is a good working solution.

Comment: @maurizio You can define new commands to abstract `varwidth` and `figure` environments, which might make the input more compact.