# Nesting "tikzpicture" within "tikzpicture" elements - Good or bad practice?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nesting

I often nest a `tikzpicture` within a `tikzpicture` element, such as a node, to treat subparts as unity and then place it as such relative to other parts of the picture. However, I'm wondering whether it is considered good or bad practice to nest `tikzpicture`s. I'm also interested of knowing the disadvantages, if any, of nesting `tikzpicture`s.

For example, in my latest figure, I've used nesting to achieve the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\colorlet{shade1}{black! 10}
\colorlet{shade2}{black! 20}
\colorlet{shade3}{black! 35}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    function/.style={%
      draw,
      circle,
      minimum size=0pt,
      inner sep=2pt,
      outer sep=0pt,
      node distance=0pt,
    },
    function argument/.style={%
      function,
      fill=shade3,
    },
    gpgpu kernel/.style={%
      function,
      fill=shade2,
    },
    invoker/.style={%
      function,
      fill=shade1,
    },
    label/.style={%
      rectangle,
      inner sep=0pt,
      outer sep=0pt,
      node distance=6pt,
    },
  ]

  % Functions
  \node [invoker, inner sep=-2pt] {%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node [gpgpu kernel] (gpgpu_kernel) {%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
          \node [function argument] (func_arg) {%
            \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
              C \\
              function
            \end{tabular}
          };
          \node [label, below=of func_arg] {GPGPU kernel};
        \end{tikzpicture}
      };
      \node [label, below=of gpgpu_kernel] {Invoker};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Related: [tikz : how to refer to a node, in nested nodes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40192)

Comment: One disadvantage is that most settings on the outer picture and also enabled for the inner pictures. So doesn't allow you to copy and past any picture into a node and still have the same output. Some settings might be difficult to reset to the default value. A method to avoid this is to store the inner pictures into saved boxes before and only use these boxes inside the other picture.

Comment: Also related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47359/how-to-typeset-a-tikz-picture-inside-a-node, and the question linked from there.

Comment: Here's one of my favourites on this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46598/86 Basically, *Bad* practice, but as with all such it can be done if done with extreme care.  I would recommend avoiding it if at all possible, and certainly just for positioning then it is always possible to do within a single picture.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think node nesting is not required (and not recommended for reasons in the linked questions) except for really complicated cases where you can't replicate the contents of a node in a straightforward fashion. However, in this specific case it is certainly doable with even less labor. You can even consider using the fit library for more complicated nesting etc. I chose to use opacity settings and the shade builds up automatically as we lay one on top of the other.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{somestyle/.style={draw,circle,fill,fill opacity=0.1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[somestyle,
        inner sep=1.7cm,
        label={[below = -0.9 cm,name=invtext]south:Invoker}] (invcirc) at (6,0) {};
\node[somestyle,
        inner sep=1.2cm,
        label={[below = -1cm,name=gptext]south:GPGU kernel},
        above= 0.1cm of invtext,
        anchor=south] (gpcirc) {};
\node[somestyle,
        above= 0.1cm of gptext,
        anchor=south,
        align=center,
        fill opacity=0.15, % For that extra 5 percent in shade3
        text opacity=1 % To recover the text color
     ] (Cfun) {C\\function};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]