# How to cross out a child of a node in a tikz tree?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

Consider this simple tikz tree:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,shapes,snakes}

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{mynode} = [text width=4em, text centered]
\begin{tikzpicture}[]

\node{My Root}
child{node[mynode]{Good Morning}}
child{node[mynode, cross out]{Good Afternoon}}
child{node[mynode]{Good Evening}}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This code produces the following:

[image]

However, I was expecting that the "Good afternoon" node should 
be crossed out, since there was something similar [here](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/node-shapes/).

How can I make a cancelling 'X' appear over that particular node?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to put `,draw` along with `cross out`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,shapes,decorations}

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{mynode} = [text width=4em, text centered]
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node{My Root}
child{node[mynode]{Good Morning}}
child{node[mynode, cross out,draw]{Good Afternoon}}
child{node[mynode]{Good Evening}};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want colour, use `draw=red` or any colour.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I needed, and the most simple solution. Could you provide a quick explanation why the 'draw' had to be added?

Comment: @geo909 A node needs `draw` to have its borders drawn. Try `\node {ABC};` and `\node[draw]{ABC};`. You will see the difference. Without `draw` only the contents are displayed. Otherwise, it is only a `\path`, a line without ink.

Answer (score 2):

This is based on [Jesse's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/199239/) but uses a style definition rather than nesting `tikzpicture` environments:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{trees,shapes.misc}
\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[
      mynode/.append style={text width=4em, align=center},
      tcancel/.append style={draw=#1, cross out, inner sep=1pt},
    ]

    \node{My Root}
    child{node[mynode]{Good Morning}}
    child{node[mynode,tcancel=red]{Good Afternoon}}
    child{node[mynode]{Good Evening}};
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: crossing out with styles]

Answer (score 1):

This is one possible solution where `\tcancel` macro was defined. #1 = color preferred. #2 is the content.

```
\newcommand{\tcancel}[2][black]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw=#1,cross out,inner sep=1pt] (a){#2};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
```

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,shapes,snakes}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\newcommand{\tcancel}[2][black]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw=#1,cross out,inner sep=1pt] (a){#2};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{mynode} = [text width=4em, text centered]
\begin{tikzpicture}[]

\node{My Root}
child{node[mynode]{Good Morning}}
child{node[mynode]{\tcancel[red]{Good Afternoon}}}
child{node[mynode]{Good Evening}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Isn't it problematic to use a `tikzpicture` within another one? That is, I've seen this said though I don't understand TikZ well enough to know. (On the other hand, this seems to be what happens if you use symbols from `tikzsymbols` in a `tikzpicture` and that seems to work OK.)

Comment: Hi @cfr, I am aware of your remark and this link http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51193/34618. In addtion, I also tried (but failed just now) to find a 200 or 500 bounty question that I saw a couple of days ago in this site using nested tikz and got bounty. Personally, I do use nested tikz and did not get me errors.