# Uncover segments of a TikZ path in Beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, overlays

I have a question about uncovering segments of a `TikZ` path in `Beamer`? As a simple example, consider the following path made up of a horizontal and a vertical segment.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw(0,0)--(1,0)--(1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

On the slide, I want to show the horizontal segment first, and then the vertical segment. One way to do this is the following:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw<1->(0,0)--(1,0);
  \draw<2->(1,0)--(1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

However, this produces two disjoint line segments (it's clear if you zoom in on the point `(1,0)`). Is there an alternative way to uncover the two segments as a *connected* path, rather than two disjoint lines?

Comment: Related: [Beamer vs. TikZ: uncover nodes step-by-step](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9094/beamer-vs-tikz-uncover-nodes-step-by-step?rq=1)?

Comment: Another related post: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6135/how-to-make-beamer-overlays-with-tikz-node

Comment: @hpesoj626, thanks and I read these posts before. But what the methods mentioned therein work for overlays between different `TikZ` commands (i.e. they are about overlays between `\sometikzcommand1[options] <overlay_part_1>;` and `\sometikzcommand2[options] <overlay_part_2>;`). In my problem, however, I need overlay within ONE `TikZ` command, i.e. `\tikzcommand[options] <overlay_part_1> ... <overlay_part_2>`. I'm not sure I see how to apply the methods suggested in those two posts...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The “related” and in the comments linked question deal, sadly, only with content that is not on one path.

## The manual solution

*Creating two paths,* where the second (longer one) is only uncovered in the second slide.

```
\visible<1>{\draw(0,0)--(1,0);}
\visible<2->{\draw(0,0)--(1,0)--(1,1);}
```

We could use the first `\draw` without `\visible` as it just gets over-drawn, but maybe you want to play around with `opacity` or hide stuff again.

## The better (?) solution

Changing the `line to` in the first slide to `move to` <sup><sub>(better would be `just leave me alone but use the correct bounding box so that the picture doesn't jump around` but in this case it works just fine)</sub><sup>†</sup></sup>.

In this particular minimal example, `beamer` doesn't know that there's a second slide when we use only `onslide=<1>`, so we need to clarify that.

### Variant A

Specifying the second (and following) operation as `line to` or empty as the default `to` path is `line to` (a.k.a. `--`).

### Variant B

Creating a second slide somehow (`\only<2>{}`), again using the fact that the default `to` is a `line to` operation.

### Better-er

Creating a TikZ style that combines hiding and showing.

```
hideshow/.style args={<#1><#2>#3}{%
    onslide=<#1>{move to},
    onslide=<#2>{#3}
}
```

## Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
    onslide/.code args={<#1>#2}{% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6155/16595
        \only<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}
    },
    hideshow/.style args={<#1><#2>#3}{%
        onslide=<#1>{move to},
        onslide=<#2>{#3}
    }
}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}% manual
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5,very thick]
\visible<1>{\draw(0,0)--(1,0);}
\visible<2->{\draw(0,0)--(1,0)--(1,1);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}% "better" A
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5,very thick]
\draw(0,0)--(1,0) to[onslide=<1>{move to},onslide=<2>{}] (1,1);% or onslide=<2>{line to}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}\only<2>{}% "better" B
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5,very thick]
\draw(0,0)--(1,0) to[onslide=<1>{move to}] (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}% "better-er"
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5,very thick]
\draw(0,0)--(1,0) to[hideshow=<1><2>{}] (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

## Output (cropped)

[image]
[image]

---

<sup>†</sup> Apparently such key is not needed, see the output of the following code:

```
\documentclass[beamer]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
    onslide/.code args={<#1>#2}{
        \only<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}
    },
    hideshow/.style args={<#1><#2>#3}{%
        onslide=<#1>{move to},
        onslide=<#2>{#3}
    }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5,very thick]
\draw[line width=1cm,line join=round](0,0)--(1,0) to[hideshow=<1><2->{}] (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Next code shows how to use decoration library to draw a path step by step in several beamer frames. I mixed [Jake's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25395/1952) to [How to animate a path or how to draw starting fraction of a complex but linear path?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25394/how-to-animate-a-path-or-how-to-draw-starting-fraction-of-a-complex-but-linear-p) and overlay drawing possibilities of `path` shown in [Prim's algorithm](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/prims-algorithm/) example on [TeXample.net](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/).

The complete code is

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}

% A simple empty decoration, that is used to ignore the last bit of the path
\pgfdeclaredecoration{ignore}{final}
{
\state{final}{}
}

% Declare the actual decoration.
\pgfdeclaremetadecoration{middle}{initial}{
    \state{initial}[
        width={0pt},
        next state=middle
    ]
    {\decoration{moveto}}

    \state{middle}[
        width={\pgfdecorationsegmentlength*\pgfmetadecoratedpathlength},
        next state=final
    ]
    {\decoration{curveto}}

    \state{final}
    {\decoration{ignore}}
}

% Create a key for easy access to the decoration
\tikzset{middle segment/.style={decoration={middle},decorate, segment length=#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[fill=blue!15,draw] at (0,0) (a) {A};
    \node[fill=blue!15,draw] at (2,2) (b) {B};
   \foreach \pos in {0.25,0.5,0.75,1}
        \path<+->[draw, middle segment=\pos, thick, red] (a) -| (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

and the result (in one compound figure while I learn how to make animated gifs) is

[image]

Two first frames show a different thickness here due a rendering problem with the viewer.