# Animated arrows

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, arrows

I would like to animate red arrows, some one would help me? thank you.

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\usepackage{graphics}


\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{tikz}

\texhash
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\begin{document}



\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,very thick](1) at (0,0){A};
\node[draw,very thick](2) at (5,2){B};
\node[draw,very thick](3) at (3,-2){C};
\node[draw,very thick](6) at (7,-2){D};
\node[draw,very thick](7) at (10,0){E };
\node[draw,very thick](8) at (0,-4){F};
\node[draw,very thick](9) at (3,-4){G};
\node[draw,very thick](10) at (7,-4){H};
\node[draw,very thick](11) at (10,-4){I};
\draw[->] [>=stealth,red,very thick](1) to (2);
\draw[->] [>=stealth,red,very thick](1) to (3);
\draw[->] [>=stealth,red,very thick](2) to (7);
\draw[->] [>=stealth,very thick](6) to (7);
\draw[->] [>=stealth,very thick](3) to (6);
\draw[->] [>=stealth,very thick](3) to (6);
\draw[->] [>=stealth,very thick](8) to (9);
\draw[->] [>=stealth,very thick](9) to (3);
\draw[->] [>=stealth,very thick](9) to (10);
\draw[->] [>=stealth,very thick](10) to (11);
\draw[->] [>=stealth,very thick](11) to (7);
\draw[->] [>=stealth,red,very thick](2) to (6);
\draw[->] [>=stealth,very thick](10) to (6);
\draw[->] [>=stealth,very thick](3) to (11);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: And where is `\begin{document}`? ;)  And most importantly: *why* animate arrows?  If you want them to attract attention, better make them red/big/encircled etc.

Comment: Please be more specific in terms of what you mean by "animate".

Comment: they appear little by little like this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78310/powerpoints-smart-art-for-tikz

Comment: So why not use beamer's overlays?  What exactly is the problem?

Comment: If you need to animate path fragments instead of complete paths can use `decorations`. An example of use with beamer's syntax in  http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83468/1952 and with animate http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/75797/1952

Answer (score 6):

You can reveal the red paths later, than the others, by using

```
\draw<2->[->,red] ... ;
```

which reveals the path on the second click.

## Example

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,very thick,every node/.style={draw}]
        \node(1) at (0,0){A};
        \node(2) at (5,2){B};
        \node(3) at (3,-2){C};
        \node(6) at (7,-2){D};
        \node(7) at (10,0){E };
        \node(8) at (0,-4){F};
        \node(9) at (3,-4){G};
        \node(10) at (7,-4){H};
        \node(11) at (10,-4){I};
        \draw<2->[->,red](1) to (2);
        \draw<3->[->,red](1) to (3);
        \draw<4->[->,red](2) to (7);
        \draw[->](6) to (7);
        \draw[->](3) to (6);
        \draw[->](3) to (6);
        \draw[->](8) to (9);
        \draw[->](9) to (3);
        \draw[->](9) to (10);
        \draw[->](10) to (11);
        \draw[->](11) to (7);
        \draw<5->[->,red](2) to (6);
        \draw[->](10) to (6);
        \draw[->](3) to (11);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

> [image]